# Google Docs API : How to update alignment of the table?

Tags: google-docs-api, google-api-python-client

I have a `Table` in the google docs and want to change its alignment to `-0.71` but i do not see any Python API to change table properties. This can be done easily using following UI on google UI (as shown below):

I also tries looking at following `requests` but could not find it:

```
updateTableColumnProperties
updateTableCellStyle
```

For debugging, i created a doc with mentioned alignment and tried dumping JSON of it. But i do not see `alignment` keyword in the JSON.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @jescanellas for reply.

I found a hack, this may not be the best solution but works.

1) Update paragraph style and set the indentation, alignment as required. Here the start_idx is the index where table needs to be created.

```
request = [{
     'updateParagraphStyle': {
         'paragraphStyle': {
             'namedStyleType': 'HEADING_5',
             'direction': 'LEFT_TO_RIGHT',
             'alignment': 'START',
             'indentFirstLine': {
                 'magnitude': -51.839999999999996,
                 'unit': 'PT'
             },
             'indentStart': {
                 'magnitude': -51.839999999999996,
                 'unit': 'PT'
             },
         },
         'fields': '*',
         'range': {
               'startIndex': start_idx,
               'endIndex':  end_idx
         }
     }
 }]
```

2) Create the table, it will get created at new indented place.

```
request = [{
       'insertTable': {
           'rows': 1,
           'columns': 1,
           'location': {
             'segmentId':'',
             'index': start_idx
           }
       },
   }]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible to do so. You can create a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=555502&template=1211190) for the Docs API, and you can also subscribe to [this one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764951) for Apps Script by clicking on the star next to the Issue number to give more priority to the request and to receive updates.

In case of the second request being implemented, you could call the script from the command line using [Clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp).

Comment: Thanks @jescanellas, i found a hack to solve the problem.